# Angular working with big size images in porject

Tags: angular

I have the problem kind of big size of production version of my Angular 7th project. 
I recently added to my project folder many images(100+) with high resolution. However, when I build my Angular project with option `--prod`, then the size of dist(builded source) become 400mb+. How can I decrease the size of my builded source? Of course still working with high resolution images in future :)

Thank you!

Comment: The angular build can't decrease the size of your images. Your only options are either compressing your images (and losing quality) or hosting them on a separate server and requesting them from the angular app.

Comment: Yeah if you have a lot of images it might be better to request them from the server seperate from your SPA

Answer (score 0):

For serving static images you better use CDN like Cloudflare and server like NGINX, no need to serve them inside your angular application.

this is how it can look in NGINX configuration

```
server {
    root /www/data;

    location / {
    }

    location /images/ {
    }
}
```

for more details check this documentation
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/